# Laravel notification channel to Telegram

Tags: laravel, notifications, queue, telegram

I want to send my articles to my Telegram channel automatically by the date time I have scheduled, so I should use queue or cron job.

I have used queue, so in local development to send notifications to telegram  I refresh the webpage, I don't want it like this, when deployed to production I want it to auto-send when I have scheduled.

Answer (score 1):

I think the cron job will suits best for the scenario, kindly refer the task scheduling from the laravel documentation for the same : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling

Answer (score 1):

You should create a Laravel Command. Take you code from the controller and put it there.

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Console\Commands;
 
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
 
class SendTelegram extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'command:telegram';
  
    protected $description = 'Send a Telegram channel';
 
    
    public function handle()
    {
        /*Here your code*/
    }
}
```

Then, add a schedule: app/Console/Kernel.php

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('command:telegram')
                 ->everyMinute();
    }
```

Finally; using terminal

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

Also, you can create a schedule cron to run your command:telegram